# Dynamics Terminology Question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Let's say you have a mass suspended by a string attached to the ceiling. You can then say that $T = mg$. In this equation, what are $T$ and $mg$? Are they vectors or vector components, or perhaps something else entirely?

Comment: Note: this is statics, not dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

$T = mg$, means that the tension int the string = the weight of the object $mg$. We are equation two opposite forces as $F_{net}$ = $ma$ = 0, as $a$ = 0.

You can refer to https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Tension-in-Physics to know more on the basics of how to calculate tension. It is basically a force, which always acts in a ‘pulling’ sense as string can only pull (when string is taut) and not push (for it would become slack).

Hoped it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $T=m g$ that corresponds to static equilibrium of the spring-mass system is a component of the force vector along the direction of gravity.

The full vector equation would be just the net force is zero

$$ \vec{T} + m \vec{g} = \vec{0} \tag{1}$$

with tension pointing upwards $$\vec{T}=\pmatrix{0\\T}$$ and gravity pointing downwards $$\vec{g}=\pmatrix{0\\-g}$$

Use in the vector force balance to get

$$ \pmatrix{ 0  \\ T - m g  } = \pmatrix{0\\0} $$ if which the *y* component yield the balance $T=m g$.